# Cannot delete docker image

Tags: docker

While setting up a new build machine (CentOS 7, Docker CE 17.12.0-ce), I did a simple test:

```
docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash
```

Which worked fine, but now I can't remove the Ubuntu image.

```
[build ~]$ docker image rm ubuntu
Error: No such image: ubuntu
[build ~]$ docker image rm ubuntu:latest
Error: No such image: ubuntu:latest
[build ~]$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              latest              0458a4468cbc        24 hours ago        112MB
[build ~]$ docker rmi 0458a4468cbc
Error: No such image: 0458a4468cbc
```

It's not being used by any containers (not that that's the error anyway):

```
[build ~]$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
[build ~]$
```

I even tried the nuke-from-orbit approach:

```
[build ~]$ docker rmi $(docker images -q)
Error: No such image: 0458a4468cbc
```

And restarting the docker daemon:

```
[build ~]$ sudo systemctl restart docker
[build ~]$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              latest              0458a4468cbc        24 hours ago        112MB
[build ~]$ docker rmi 0458a4468cbc
Error: No such image: 0458a4468cbc
```

What gives? Not that it really matters that the ubuntu image is there, I just don't understand why I can't clean it up.

**Update**

I tried pulling the image again, and, well:

```
docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Digest: sha256:e27e9d7f7f28d67aa9e2d7540bdc2b33254b452ee8e60f388875e5b7d9b2b696
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
[build ~]$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              latest              0458a4468cbc        25 hours ago        112MB
ubuntu              latest              0458a4468cbc        25 hours ago        112MB
[build ~]$ docker image rm ubuntu
Untagged: ubuntu:latest
[build ~]$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              latest              0458a4468cbc        25 hours ago        112MB
[build ~]$
```

**Update 2**

Tried the same basic steps with a brand new CentOS 7 1708 install and had no problems at all, so safe to say this is just a weird one-off corruption of something on this machine.

Question still is, how do I clean it up? Is there something on the filesystem I can just `rm -rf` and let docker start fresh?

Comment: have you tried `docker images` instead of `docker image ls`, I don't think there would be a difference though.

Comment: This looks like one to report as an issue. What storage driver are you using? `docker info -f '{{ .Driver }}'` Have you tried pulling the ubuntu image again?

Comment: Driver is `devicemapper`. Running `docker images` shows the same as `docker image ls`.

Comment: My driver is `overlay2`, but with the same problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While setting up this system I had originally installed an old version of docker available from the standard CentOS repositories (`yum install centos`) instead of adding the docker repositories and installing `docker-ce`. Even though I'm on the latest version now, the old one must have introduced some bad data in `/var/lib/docker` before I upgraded. In the end I just deleted all the local image and container data and started over:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Everything is working normally now.

Comment: got exactly the same here, and your big gun approach fixed as well

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar thing, when I used rm -f, it was not working (could not delete)

```
docker rm -f <ImageId>
```

I restarted Docker Engine and I used the following command, it works.

```
docker image prune -f -a
```

Comment: This left a bunch of images listed that still report "No such image"

Answer (score 0):

You can try selecting the version of the operating system you want to delete, example:

```
docker image rm -f ubuntu:18.04
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can use docker image rm -f <ID_IMAGE>

Comment: What is new in this answer what the other answers didn't covered already?