# How to remove a docker image that cannot be found by the CLI?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am starting with `docker` and there is a docker image I cannot remove. What command should I use to purge the list of locally installed images?

What I tried:

```sh
$ docker image ls

REPOSITORY                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
dpage/pgadmin4               latest              8efd3d498978        5 months ago        245MB
```

But then removing the image does not work:

```sh
$ docker image rm dpage/pgadmin4

Error: No such image: dpage/pgadmin4
```

I also tried with the ID:

```sh
$ docker image rm 8efd3d498978

Error: No such image: 8efd3d498978
```

And tried to prune but no luck:

```sh
$ docker system prune -af

Total reclaimed space: 0B
```

Comment: try `docker rmi -f dpage/pgadmin4:latest`

Comment: Thanks @SiHa - the solution in this SO post worked. Nothing else did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue came from a previous `docker` installation that let garbage behind.

Trying clever stuff did not solve it, so used nuclear weapon (coming from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48489518/715286)):

```sh
sudo service docker stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo service docker start
```